# Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

When I go to build the project at that time I got the  error-

Error :- Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

When I opened any page then error show on every page like some library is missing but there is not ant library missing but why It's occur I did not understand .

Please help to find a solution.

Thank You for Concentration.

Comment: It's hard to find out the issue based on the information you post. What feature you are trying to implement? What's the code that you are using? Please share more information about your issue.

Comment: Thank you sir  I got solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read about the solution of this question on StackOverflow Solution of it's like the same.
I have multiple pages in my project and by mistake, some space was created between the namespace name and It's more difficult to find that page because the error did not show the location There were multiple pages But    Lucky I found that page.

Real Page Name :- **x:Class="Sample.UWP.ResidentBinder"**

and reasion for occuring error is -- **x:Class="Sample.UWP. *(space)*ResidentBinder"**